# Angular 4 dynamic routing issue with AOT

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-aot

I have an app where I need to redirect to different component depending on the URL hit by user, suppose if it's `localhost/login` it should redirect to route `localhost/login/#/login`, if `localhost/user` then `localhost/user/#/spreadsheet`, this works fine without AOT, but not with AOT, here is my function to get the redirecting route:

```
export function baseHref() {
    return ((document.location.pathname == '/login/') ? 'login' : ((document.location.pathname.split('/')[3] == 'edit') ? 'edit' : ((window.innerWidth >= 720) ? 'spreadsheet' : 'two-panel')));
}
```

And here is my route:

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
    // If path is not defined it will redirect to spreadsheet
    { path: '', redirectTo: baseHref, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'spreadsheet', component: ContactParent },
    { path: 'two-panel', component: ContactParent },
    { path: 'login', component: Login },
    { path: 'login/step1', component: LoginStep1 },
    { path: 'login/step2', component: LoginStep2 },
    { path: 'edit', component: EditSingleContact },
    { path: 'share', component: EditSingleContact }
];
```

Here it's always redirecting to `two-panel` route

Comment: I have a similar need. Were you able to resolve your problem ?

Comment: No man unfortunatly I have not found and proper solution so I handled this with some hacky stuff.. :(

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by providing routes definition to `ROUTES` using function factory... (tested on Angular 4.1.2)

Modify your AppModule (app.module.ts):

change RouterModul.forRoot in imports array

```
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
...
```

to

```
RouterModule.forRoot([])
```

add this two providers in providers array:

```
... ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS
} from '@angular/core';
...  ROUTES,
} from '@angular/router';
...
providers: [
{provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, multi: true, useValue: routes},
{provide: ROUTES, multi: true, useFactory: getRoutes},
...
```

define factory function (at top of the app.module.ts file):

```
export function getRoutes() {
  return routes;
}
```

maybe you need also create new file eg: `app.routes.ts` and put your routes definitions there

```
export const routes: Routes = [
            {
                path: '',
...
```

and import it in AppModule (app.module.ts).

```
import { routes } from './app.routes';
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but unfortunately it messed up with lazy loading modules.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 5+

Global (document, window etc.) variables are in time of AOT compilation undefined. So the compilator removes them.

Solution that works with JIT and AOT:

In AppComponent `app.component.ts`:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.resetConfig(appRoutes)
}
```

then define routes as usual:

File with routes `app.routes.ts`:

declare let someglobalvariable: boolean;

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
   {
     path: someglobalvariable ? '' : ':slug', component: SomeCoponent
   }
```

Using routes in AppModule class `app.module.ts`:

```
import { appRoutes } from 'app.routes.ts';
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports : {[
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ...
  ]}
}
```